# Pegar resultado de varias edittext em um Recyclerview

Tags: java, android

Eu tenho um recyclerview, sendo que estou criando para cada item da lista, um Edittext(via XML).Sendo que a finalidade daquela edittext, é ser preenchida com a quantidade de ITENS que é desejado. Logo após, chamarei um método onde devo passar cada item da lista, com a quantidade correta de acordo com a edit daquela posição. O problema, é, que toda vez que executo a acao de uma das edittext, ele sempre passa os itens da lista, porem com o campo quantidade repetido, todos iguais. Precisaria pegar o valor certo pela posição do adapter, via JAVA, mas nao sei como implementar.

Comment: Olá Souza! Por gentileza, edite sua pergunta para incluir o código que você está usando. Dessa forma ficará mais fácil lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Souza,

Você deve criar um adapter, e no método getView você define o que deverá ser apresentado em cada posição do recyclerview.

```
public class ExemploAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```